# Make custom function with if-statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, custom-function

I'm tring to make function with if statement. I want to change whichever df that is longer to sample to the other shorter df's length. But it doesn't work, throwing an error 'list index out of range'. Also, is there any better way to make this function instead of fitting another custom function within a custom function??

```
def apple(df, df2):

    if len(df) >= len(df2):
        df = df.sample(len(df2))
    else:
        df2 = df2.sample(len(df))
        
    plt.hist(df.iloc[:,1])
    plt.hist(df2.iloc[:,1])
    plt.show()

   def good(df, df2)
    one = np.histogram(df['apple1'])[0]
    two = np.histogram(df2['apple'])[0]
    return sum(one, two)
```

Comment: Why are you blaming the `if` statement for the error?  The only place I see an index here is your `[0]`  references near the end.

Comment: @RufusVS hey it's the density plot I drew although I did not include the `density=true` , which doesn't really impact my question. My code works when I do not add `if` statament and run it all separately.

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace and the code which generated it.

Comment: Is it possible the shorter df is length 0?